# The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead? Type 'Object' is missing the following properti

Tags: angular, typescript

** Angular 9 **

```
home.component.ts
```

'I am Trying to match the type and display data store in firebase database in the html page can anyone Slove this error. I am Trying to Slove this error since two days.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent  implements OnInit{

  constructor(private http:HttpService) { }

  users : any[] =  [
   
  ];

    Oncreateuser(uname:any,fame:any){
      this.users.push({
        name:uname.value,
        name2:fame.value

      })

      uname.value = ""
      fame.value = ""  
  }

  save(){
    this.http.saveitems(this.users).subscribe(
      (Response) => console.log(Response),
      (err) => err
    )
    alert('saved to firebase Database')

  }

  onremoveitem(item:any){
    this.users.splice(item, 1)
  } 
ngOnInit(){}
```

```
fetchproduct(){
  
 this.http.fetch().subscribe((Response)=>{
   console.log(Response)

 },(err)=>console.log(err))
 
 }
}
```

Comment: Which type are you trying to match? Can you add more details to the question?

Comment: Your error notification will always point to the line that provoked the error. On the first line of the notification there will be home.component.ts.xx (and a number in stead of the xx). What's that number? With which line in your code does that number correspond? Can you share that information?

Answer (score 1):

Please change this line

```
this.http.fetch()
 .subscribe(Response=>{this.users = Response})
```

to

```
this.http.fetch()
 .subscribe((Response:any)=>{this.users = Response})
```

Answer (score -1):

Just declare the following:

```
users: any = [];
```

instead of this:

```
users: any[] = [];
```